# Не работает опция SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS для SOAP сервера в php?

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework-2, wsdl

Пытаюсь получить массив, хотя в списке один элемент. Проблема описана здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050621/single-array-element-becomes-object-with-zend-soap-client  Но у меня СЕРВЕР. Пытаюсь принять этот код:

**тело запроса**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:bu="http://debug.xxxxx.loc/xxxx">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <bu:contractTypeDictionary
        SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <dictionary>
            <item>
                <V_Code>STRING</V_Code>
                <V_Name>STRING</V_Name>
                <GUID>STRING</GUID>
                <IsGroup>BOOLEAN</IsGroup>
                <GUID_Parent>STRING</GUID_Parent>
            </item>
        </dictionary>
    </bu:contractTypeDictionary>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

```
 $server = new Server();
    $server
        ->setClassmap($classMap->getClassMap())
        ->setClass($handlerClassName)
        ->setObject($handler)
        ->setOptions(['features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS])
    ;
```

Comment: не работает SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS

Comment: Покажите свой код?

Comment: добавил выше. Фреймворr zend 2